# LVM shrink in xfs partition (free the disks)

Tags: rhel, lvm

Need your suggestion on shrinking the LVM.
Currently the **repolv** lvm is distributed to 3 PV's(sdd,sde,sdf). Now I want to reduce so that to accommodate to 2 disks(sde,sdf).  Perhaps lvreduce will do the job but need the sequence of commands to execute without any data loss.Kindly suggest..

```
[root@development: /root] lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0  100G  0 disk
├─sda1                8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                8:2    0 92.7G  0 part
  ├─rootvg-LogVol00 253:0    0    6G  0 lvm  /
  ├─rootvg-LogVol04 253:1    0    8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  ├─rootvg-LogVol03 253:3    0   15G  0 lvm  /var
  ├─rootvg-LogVol02 253:4    0   10G  0 lvm  /tmp
  └─rootvg-LogVol01 253:5    0   10G  0 lvm  /opt
sdb                   8:16   0   50G  0 disk
sdc                   8:32   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-rhel6lv    253:6    0  1.5T  0 lvm  /var/www/html/RHEL6
sdd                   8:48   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-rhel7lv    253:9    0  1.5T  0 lvm  /var/www/html/RHEL7
sde                   8:64   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-repolv     253:2    0    2T  0 lvm  /var/www/html
sdf                   8:80   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-repolv     253:2    0    2T  0 lvm  /var/www/html
sdg                   8:96   0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-amzn24lv   253:7    0  1.5T  0 lvm  /var/www/html/AMZN24
sdh                   8:112  0  1.5T  0 disk
└─repovg-amzn25lv   253:8    0  1.5T  0 lvm  /var/www/html/AMZN25
sr0                  11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

[root@xyz development: /root] df -h /var/www/html/
 FileSystem                  Size  Usage Free   Usage% Mount Point
 /dev/mapper/repovg-repolv   2.0T  490G  1.5T     %    /var/www/html
```

Comment: XFS does not support shrinking. You have 3x 1.5T disks and your LV is 2T so it should easily fit on 2 drives. So does pvmove not work? Or did you set it up with striping (raid) mode? Unless there was another LV before blocking up free space, LVM should not have allocated it across three PVs in the first place.

Comment: Another alternative (in cases were shrinking would otherwise be necessary) would be to convert to a thin volume and free up extents with fstrim. Other than that you have to copy files around, to make a new smaller filesystem from scratch.

Comment: HI @frostchutz 
thank you so much for your reply. With pvmove I suceeded to shrink the lvm `/dev/sdd` . But when I tried `pvmove /dev/sde` it is prompting me there is no  freespace left. As you said it is looking to allocate 2TB of LV to `/dev/sdf` and failing. Could you  please suggest how to make free `/dev/sde` disk with no data loss. Please let me know how to check that raid stuff if needed.

Comment: So you're reducing it to 1 disk now? It's not really possible since you can't shrink the xfs filesystem. But since you have other drives around you can just make a smaller one then copy files over (rsync -a or xfs_dump / xfs_restore). If you want to be able to shrink in the future you have to use a filesystem that supports shrinking like ext4.

Comment: Thank you again.. Yes I want to shrink to one drive . you are advising to copy file to other disk from repolv LV to /dev/sdg or /dev/sdf. Then finally `lvremove /dev/repovg/repolv/` and assign new lv and copy back ..

Comment: my final goal is like below
`/dev/sdd : repovg-rhel7lv    -> Mount to /var/www/html/RHEL7
/dev/sde : repovg-rhel7awslv -> Mount to /var/www/html/RHEL7AWS
/dev/sdf : repovg-rhel8lv    -> Mount to /var/www/html/RHEL8`